# animation within ScrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I fired UIView animation within scrollViewDidScroll by modifying a PullToRefresh lib. What i want is to fire off animation when user starts to pull and terminate it when the pull to refresh header view goes off screen. However, the animation only works when user released pulling; during the time a user continues to pull, the animation doesn't work...Thanks a lot for your help in advance! :)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    if (scrollView.isDragging) {
        if (refreshHeaderView.state == EGOOPullRefreshPulling && scrollView.contentOffset.y > -65.0f && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0.0f && !_reloading) {
            [refreshHeaderView setState:EGOOPullRefreshNormal];
            if (timer) {
                [timer invalidate];
                timer = nil;
            }
        } else if (refreshHeaderView.state == EGOOPullRefreshNormal && scrollView.contentOffset.y < -65.0f && !_reloading) {
            [refreshHeaderView setState:EGOOPullRefreshPulling];
            if (!timer) {
                timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(startMyAnimation) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the programming interface itself. Thanks!

Comment: removed 'animation' tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally timers don't fire while the user is dragging in a scrollview.

Try scheduling the timer like this:

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(startMyAnimation) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```